# Algebraic Geometry and its application to Cryptography

Tags: algebraic-geometry, cryptography

I am learning Algebraic Geometry(AG) from *Shafarevich's* book. I know little bit cryptography. I know about RSA algorithm.

Few days back, through some random source, I came to know that AG has lot of application in Cryptography. Can someone explain some basic applications of AG concepts in Cryptography? I want to write a exposition on this topic in future.

Comment: There's elliptic curve (and hyperelliptic curve) cryptosystems.

Comment: Computerphile had made a couple of videos about elliptic curve cryptography. While they don't go very deep into the subject, I believe it's enough to get a feel about the concept. I think [this is the first one](https://youtube.com/watch?v=NF1pwjL9-DE).

Answer (score 0):

There are two areas I can think of: elliptic curves as mentioned in the comments, and error-correcting codes. In the second example, error-correcting codes can be made to correspond to algebraic varieties. In terms of cryptography, one can therefore try to study and use the resulting codes for code-based cryptography.